# I need to Arrange my Json data to iteratable one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
[{"TenantId":96,"BatchNo":"B-638248651272667323PI345-1","Rate":10.00,"Qty":1.00,"Discount":0.00,"Gross":10.00,"Net":10.00,"TransactionType":1,"CombinationId":null,"PurchaseInvoiceDetailsId":11394,"PurchaseInvoiceDetails":null,"SalesInvoiceDetailId":null,"SalesInvoiceDetail":null,"SalesReturnDetailsId":null,"SalesReturnDetails":null,"PurchaseReturnDetailsId":null,"PurchaseReturnDetails":null,"ProductProfileId":6490,"ProductProfile":null,"ProductVarientLinksId":null,"ProductVarientLinks":null,"ProductionOrderDetailId":null,"ProductionOrderDetail":null,"QuickSaleInvoiceDetailId":null,"QuickSaleInvoiceDetail":null,"DirectSaleDetailId":null,"DirectSaleDetail":null,"QuickPreparedItemId":null,"QuickPreparedItem":null,"QuickSaleFoodWastgeId":null,"QuickSaleFoodWastge":null,"TransferDetailId":null,"TransferDetail":null,"StoreId":245,"Store":null,"BranchId":233,"Branch":null,"UnitId":238,"Unit":null,"BaseUnitId":239,"BaseUnit":null,"BaseQty":1000.00,"DamageStockDetailsId":null,"DamageStockDetails":null,"StockUpdateDetailId":null,"StockUpdateDetail":null,"QuickSaleOrderDetailId":null,"QuickRaweMaterialsUsedId":null,"QuickRaweMaterialsUsed":null,"Date":"2023-07-13T00:00:00","BarcodeNumber":null,"CompanyId":66,"Company":null,"RawmaterialsReturnId":null,"RawmaterialsReturn":null,"FinishedGoodDetailId":null,"FinishedGoodDetail":null,"DeliveryDetailsId":null,"DeliveryDetails":null,"GrnDetailsId":null,"GrnDetails":null,"QRCodeDetailsId":null,"QRCodeDetails":null,"UPICode":null,"MaxRate":0.00,"SalesRate":0.00,"ExpiryDate":null,"SerialNumber1":null,"SerialNumber2":null,"ChasisNo":null,"MotorNo":null,"RepackingId":null,"Repacking":null,"RepackingDetailsId":null,"RepackingDetails":null,"StockCorrectionDetailsId":null,"StockCorrectionDetails":null,"PurchaseRate":0.00,"FinancialYearMastersId":312,"FinancialYearMasters":null,"Reference":null,"IsDeleted":false,"DeleterUserId":null,"DeletionTime":null,"LastModificationTime":null,"LastModifierUserId":null,"CreationTime":"2023-07-13T17:27:14.3584215","CreatorUserId":253,"Id":47819}]
```

This is my Json data and this varying the key values so i need to loop with the below format
eg: [ {"TenantId":96},{"BatchNo":"B-638248651272667323PI345-1"}  ]

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to *split* the object with multiple properties to multiple objects for each property?

Comment: yes i want to that format the problem is key values will e change dynamically added to array what its come from backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` over the entries of each object to create an object from each key-value pair.

```js
const data=[{"TenantId":96,"BatchNo":"B-638248651272667323PI345-1","Rate":10.00,"Qty":1.00,"Discount":0.00,"Gross":10.00,"Net":10.00,"TransactionType":1,"CombinationId":null,"PurchaseInvoiceDetailsId":11394,"PurchaseInvoiceDetails":null,"SalesInvoiceDetailId":null,"SalesInvoiceDetail":null,"SalesReturnDetailsId":null,"SalesReturnDetails":null,"PurchaseReturnDetailsId":null,"PurchaseReturnDetails":null,"ProductProfileId":6490,"ProductProfile":null,"ProductVarientLinksId":null,"ProductVarientLinks":null,"ProductionOrderDetailId":null,"ProductionOrderDetail":null,"QuickSaleInvoiceDetailId":null,"QuickSaleInvoiceDetail":null,"DirectSaleDetailId":null,"DirectSaleDetail":null,"QuickPreparedItemId":null,"QuickPreparedItem":null,"QuickSaleFoodWastgeId":null,"QuickSaleFoodWastge":null,"TransferDetailId":null,"TransferDetail":null,"StoreId":245,"Store":null,"BranchId":233,"Branch":null,"UnitId":238,"Unit":null,"BaseUnitId":239,"BaseUnit":null,"BaseQty":1000.00,"DamageStockDetailsId":null,"DamageStockDetails":null,"StockUpdateDetailId":null,"StockUpdateDetail":null,"QuickSaleOrderDetailId":null,"QuickRaweMaterialsUsedId":null,"QuickRaweMaterialsUsed":null,"Date":"2023-07-13T00:00:00","BarcodeNumber":null,"CompanyId":66,"Company":null,"RawmaterialsReturnId":null,"RawmaterialsReturn":null,"FinishedGoodDetailId":null,"FinishedGoodDetail":null,"DeliveryDetailsId":null,"DeliveryDetails":null,"GrnDetailsId":null,"GrnDetails":null,"QRCodeDetailsId":null,"QRCodeDetails":null,"UPICode":null,"MaxRate":0.00,"SalesRate":0.00,"ExpiryDate":null,"SerialNumber1":null,"SerialNumber2":null,"ChasisNo":null,"MotorNo":null,"RepackingId":null,"Repacking":null,"RepackingDetailsId":null,"RepackingDetails":null,"StockCorrectionDetailsId":null,"StockCorrectionDetails":null,"PurchaseRate":0.00,"FinancialYearMastersId":312,"FinancialYearMasters":null,"Reference":null,"IsDeleted":false,"DeleterUserId":null,"DeletionTime":null,"LastModificationTime":null,"LastModifierUserId":null,"CreationTime":"2023-07-13T17:27:14.3584215","CreatorUserId":253,"Id":47819}];
const res = data.flatMap(o => Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]:v})));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce!  I think this is what you are asking for, it takes the object and splits it into individual key/values.  You can use .flat() to get to get rid of the nested arrays if you want.

```js
function transformArray(array) {
  return array.reduce((transformedArray, item) => {
    const transformedItem = Object.entries(item).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      acc.push({ [key]: value });
      return acc;
    }, []);
    transformedArray.push(transformedItem);
    return transformedArray;
  }, []);
}

const originalArray = [
  { "foo": "1", "bar": "2", "batch" : "1235", "price": "10.00" },
  { "foo": "3", "bar": "4" }
];

const transformedArray = transformArray(originalArray);
console.log(transformedArray);
```